# Call to GSSContext.initSecContext fails intermittently: Receive timed out

Tags: java, authentication, configuration, windows-authentication, kerberos

I'm writing client-side code for Windows Kerberos authentication with a service (logging code omitted):

```java
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
// System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
Package thisPkg = AuthHelper.class.getPackage();
String configPath = Util.getConfigPath(thisPkg, "jaas.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "=" + configPath);
GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
GSSName peerName = manager.createName(spn, GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
GSSContext context = manager.createContext(peerName, null, null,
    GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
context.requestMutualAuth(true); // required
context.requestCredDeleg(true); // required for publish
byte[] serverTokenBytes = new byte[0];
while (!context.isEstablished()) {
  byte[] clientTokenBytes = context.initSecContext(serverTokenBytes, 0,
      serverTokenBytes.length);
  if (clientTokenBytes != null)
    socket.send(createClientMessage(clientTokenBytes));
  if (context.isEstablished()) break;
  Message message = socket.receive();
  String serverToken = message.getFirst("SERVERTOKEN").toString();
  serverTokenBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(serverToken);
}
```

Where `jaas.conf` simply contains:

```
sp {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

I have also set the `allowtgtsessionkey` registry key as required, and installed [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html).

The code sometimes works (i.e. mutual authentication is established); however, sometimes it gets stuck for a while at the first call to `GSSContext.initSecContext`, throwing an exception after about a minute:

```
Exception in thread "main" GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Receive timed out)
  ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
  ...
```

When I enable Kerberos debugging output (by uncommenting the second line above), I can see that the protocol sometimes gets stuck at line:

```
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
```

[A Java Kerberos troubleshooting website](http://www.informatik.hs-furtwangen.de/doku/java/j2sdk-1_4_1-doc/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html) suggests that this is an issue with the Kerberos authentication server, but I know that the server is up and running, since we have similar code written in C# (using .NET libraries) that never gets stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the DNS resolution for the Kerberos authentication server is going through some indirection, which is unreliable. If you specify the server explicitly (somewhere at the beginning of your code), it will bypass that redirection:

```java
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "<YOUR_KRB_REALM>");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "<YOUR_KRB_SERVER_ADDR_OR_IP>");
```

**EDIT**: It turns out that communication with Kerberos servers was inherently unreliable due to the protocol using UDP, so it had a high chance of failing for servers that are relatively far away. Windows 8 uses TCP by default; to **force TCP** on previous versions:

- **XP/2000**: In `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos`, set **DWORD** `MaxPacketSize` to `1`.
- **2003/Vista/7**: In `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters`, set **DWORD** `MaxPacketSize` to `1`.

*(Note that the same registry directory also needs **DWORD** `AllowTGTSessionKey` set to `1` for Kerberos to work at all.)*

Comment: If you, your admin MUST fix DNS.